# What does A->A and VV->V etc. mean in the `ffmpeg -filters` command output?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am seeing this:

```
Filters:
  T.. = Timeline support
  .S. = Slice threading
  ..C = Command support
  A = Audio input/output
  V = Video input/output
  N = Dynamic number and/or type of input/output
  | = Source or sink filter
... abench            A->A       Benchmark part of a filtergraph.
..C acompressor       A->A       Audio compressor.
... acontrast         A->A       Simple audio dynamic range compression/expansion filter.
... acopy             A->A       Copy the input audio unchanged to the output.
... acue              A->A       Delay filtering to match a cue.
... acrossfade        AA->A      Cross fade two input audio streams.
...
TSC colormap          VVV->V     Apply custom Color Maps to video stream.
TS. colormatrix       V->V       Convert color matrix.
TS. colorspace        V->V       Convert between colorspaces.
TSC colortemperature  V->V       Adjust color temperature of video.
TSC convolution       V->V       Apply convolution filter.
TS. convolve          VV->V      Convolve first video stream with second video stream.
...
```

A few questions:

1. What does this part of the filters intro mean?

   ```
    A = Audio input/output
    V = Video input/output
    N = Dynamic number and/or type of input/output
    | = Source or sink filter
   ```
2. What does the `A->A` and `VVV->V` (and any combination of 1+ A or 1+ V) mean?
3. Where do the `N` and `|` show up, I don't see it anywhere...

I am hoping to [convert this CLI data output to JSON](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/33f746574c679a3e815ee7724bc75e65#file-parse-js-L2254), but don't know what those mean.

Comment: as the ffmpeg tag states: **Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/**. Please delete this.

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A->A` means the filter takes in one audio input stream and emits one audio stream.

`VVV->V` means the filter takes in three video input streams and emits one video stream.

The amix filter has `N->A` which means it takes in a dynamic number of inputs and emits one audio output stream.

The concat filter has `N->N` which means dynamic number of inputs and dynamic number of outputs.

The avsynctest filter has `|->AV` which means it generates its input and emits 1 video + 1 audio stream.

nullsink filter has `V->|` which means it takes in one video input stream and flushes it to null. Useful when a stream is required as a reference but has no further use.